# Proper way of testing Kafka, Spark and ES integration

Tags: java, apache-spark, elasticsearch, junit, apache-kafka

I have a very common problem, yet I am unable to find the "right" or "correct" way to test this

I have a simple Spark job that gets events from Kafka (events are in protobuf format), applies some transformations on them and then stores the result in ES. I am saving single events

I need to know how to test this properly. I am using BulkProcessor, therefore, I am manually committing the offsets when I think they should be. Therefore, it makes sense to test this workflow properly because I don't want to lose events

My understanding is that I need to have a mock Kafka instance, need to call the appropriate function that handles all the transformations and then store the result in ES. However, I don't how to do all this. Also, I don't know how to write test events in protobuf format into Kafka topics

P.S. I am NOT using Spring framework

Comment: Could you use something like TestContainers to set up a Kafka instance that you could use in your tests?

Comment: @Gavin should I create mock Kafka instance and producers who first produce data to Kafka and then the Spark job consumes from it?

Comment: Using something like TestContainers you are building actual instances as far as I am aware, they are basically docker containers.  This allows you to "quickly" spin one up, throw messages at it and ensure your integration is working.  Depending on you use cases I would suggest for this type of testing you just want to test the happy path, and the error path(s).

Comment: Thankyou @Gavin!
I think I understand your point. I'll do something similar to this